# Intuition behind Hit or Miss operator in Mathematical morphology

Tags: general-topology

> The key principle underlying mathematical morphology is to gain topological or geometrical information about a binary image $X \subset E$ by probing it with another small set $A$, called a structuring element, at every position $h \in E$. By "probing" we mean testing whether the set$A_h$ hits $X$ (i.e, $A_h \cap X \neq \phi$) misses $X$ (i.e, $A_h \cap X = \phi$), or lies entirely inside $X$
>
> $ X \circledast (A,B) = \{ h \in E| A_h \subset X  $ $ \text{and}$ $   B_h \subset X^C \}$
>
> Heijmans, H. J. (1995). Mathematical morphology: A modern approach in image processing based on algebra and geometry. SIAM review, 37(1), 1-36.

Why is that we have to probe the image and background together? The preceding text suggests to me that only probing the image is needed.

Comment: This document : https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00512735/document gives some hints.

Comment: What page specifically @JeanMarie

Comment: From page 3, the review of all the existing HMT for **gray levels** images : I realize now that your question is for **binary** images which is simpler.